# Как сделать в простом html сайте ссылки без html на конце

Tags: .htaccess

Хочу чтобы ссылки были такого вида: site.ru/xxx/ site.ru/xxx/xxx/ site.ru/xxx/xxx/xxx/ и т.д Нужно именно правило в htacces, чтобы не прописывать редирект для каждой страницы.

Answer (score 2):

Господи, перенаправляйте все запросы на главную, а потом парсите этот URL, напишите класс, который будет этим заниматься.Для редиректа nginx (прям в конфиге в location \ -

```
if (!-f $request_filename) {rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php;}
```

(ну это если у вас PHP, если что-то другое, думаю сами знаете что делать=)Для .htaccess -

```
Options -IndexesRewriteEngine OnRewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-fRewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-dRewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

(ну и конечно mod_rewrite On)